# Interfacing issue with esp8266 esp-01 module and mpu6050

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, esp8266, mpu6050, qgyroscopereading

I used the `Arduino` uno to upload the sketch to the esp 01 module. I attached the image how I connected the `esp-01` and `mpu6050`, browser continuously prints the gyro values but incrementing by 0.01 I need actual gyro values

```
[1]
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <MPU6050_tockn.h>
#include <Wire.h>

MPU6050 mpu6050(Wire);

const char* ssid = "TP-LINK";
const char* password = "1913131";

// Create an instance of the server
// specify the port to listen on as an argument
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);


  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());



  delay(5000);
  //Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin(0,2);
  delay(1000);


  mpu6050.begin();
  delay(1000);
  mpu6050.calcGyroOffsets(true);

  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected

  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    Serial.print("Client did not connect");
    delay(1000);

    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while (!client.available()) {
    delay(1);
  }

  while(client.available()){
  mpu6050.update();

  client.print(mpu6050.getGyroAngleX());
  client.print(",");
  client.print(mpu6050.getGyroAngleY());
  client.print(",");
  client.println(mpu6050.getGyroAngleZ());
  delay(10);

  }

  delay(1);

  Serial.println("Client disonnected");

  // The client will actually be disconnected
  // when the function returns and 'client' object is detroyed
}

> Blockquote
```

when client actually connects and when I enter the ip address in the browser  values printed in the browser are 0.69,0.69,0.60 0.70,0.70,0.60 0.70 and goes on incrementing the values by 0.01 but I need actual gyroscope reading. help me please

I connected the esp 01 and mpu6050 like in this image
List item

Comment: [this is image connection description](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sbsth_7OMh-fFSK1gckQO1JVPMl778UF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using MPU 6050 library just use Wire Library to get the values refer to the data sheet of MPU6050 uses address 0x68 to start trnsmission.

```
 Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
```

you can refer to following [datasheet](https://media.ncd.io/sites/2/20170721134617/PS-MPU-6000A-00v3.4.pdf). To get the Gyro values we write to 0x1B(MSB) and 0x18(LSB). We will get the 6 bytes of data

```
 // Select gyroscope configuration register
 Wire.write(0x1B);
 Wire.write(0x18);
```

now write to data register 0x43 to recieve the gyro values. We will receive 6 bytes of values from the sensor where the 16 bits(1byte) for x, y and z axis respectively
     Wire.requestFrom(Addr, 6);

```
// Read 6 byte of data 
if(Wire.available() == 6)
{
   data[0] = Wire.read();
   data[1] = Wire.read();
   data[2] = Wire.read();
   data[3] = Wire.read();
   data[4] = Wire.read();
   data[5] = Wire.read(); 
 }
 // Convert the data
   int xGyro = data[0] * 256 + data[1];
   int yGyro = data[2] * 256 + data[3];
   int zGyro = data[4] * 256 + data[5];
```

where as To get accelerometer values we write to 0x1C(MSB) and 0x18(LSB). you can find the full code in this [github link](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/MPU-6000/blob/master/Arduino/MPU-6000.ino). Here we have got the gyro and accelerometer values from the sensor

also Do it like this Wire.begin(SDA,SCL) in your case it would be Wire.begin(0,2);
*Note MPU6000 and MPU6050 have the same specification and address so don't worry about that.

Comment: That's fine  I am testing it today. and I will come back. Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: your code has wire.begin(sda, scl) first and after then in the next line serial.begin(baud rate);  and your code works thank you so much

Comment: Welcome, this doesn't have any specified sequence you can do it vice versa also

Comment: Thanks for your help I get the raw values now not degrees of rotation. Can you please help me on how the degrees/sec works

Answer (score 0):

The full-scale range of GYRO can be detected from register address 0x1B, there are different resolution ranging from 250 to 2000 degree/sec to get the exact value of the the axis of rotation you need to divide your raw values with the scale factor defined in the following [datasheet](https://store.invensense.com/datasheets/invensense/MPU-6050_DataSheet_V3%204.pdf) in Gyroscope specification column. this is sensitivity/scale factor. The raw values you are getting are the decimal values and this scale factor is in LSB(degree/sec). for example if you have chosen 500 deg/sec then you need to devide it by 65.5 to get the value